# Flatlist of videos does not render in react native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of videos rendering, and after 32 videos render I receive this error:

```
domain: "AVFoundationErrorDomain", code: -11839
```

This is because iOS will only allow 32 video players to be instantiated at once. How, then, can I get rid of some of the video players? The Flatlist is horizontal and wrapped by a vertically scrolling recyclerlist view. The code for the flatlist is here:

```
      <FlatList
                    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref }}
                    data={this.state.posts}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    onScroll={(e) => this.pauseAll(e)}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    scrollEnabled={this.state.isPortrait}
                    horizontal={true}
                    renderAheadOffset={0}
                    initialNumToRender={3}
                    windowSize={3}
                    removeClippedSubviews={true}
                    pagingEnabled={true}
                    keyExtractor={(row, id) => id.toString()}
                    renderItem={(row, id) => (this.renderVideos())}
/>
```

My understanding is that recyclerlistview would not hold each row in memory, only the dimensions, but all 32 videos are in memory.

Another way to put this is that original video players do not unmount when out of view?

Comment: I'm currently struggling with the same issue. I believe the general idea is to render image(thumbnail) with press handler to play the yet to mount video. This press handler should check if the list-item isViewable or not, and setState to render the actual video component.
it doesn't seem a simple task anyhow